# Autohotkey sometimes stuck

Tags: autohotkey, skype

**Prehistory:**

Some time ago Skype has assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey to make a new call. This setting can't be disabled.

Sometimes I confuse browser window with Skype window and made a call to many people instead of refreshing browser window (I need to refresh browser window  very often because of profession).

So I made a script to prevent sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey to Skype window, it works perfect, but sometimes I can't send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> anywhere, not only Skype window.

**Code:**

```
;#NoTrayIcon
$^r::
WinGetClass, class, A

if (class != "TConversationForm")
Send ^r
return
```

**Compiled binary:** http://random.net.ua/SkypePreventHotkey.exe

**Autohotkey version:** 1.1.14.03

Comment: 1) What does "sometimes" mean? Is there a certain pattern/certain windows in which it fails? 2) Try this code instead: `#IfWinActive ahk_class TConversationForm ^r::return` (insert a line break before `^r`). 3) Are you aware that `F5` is usually also a hotkey to refresh a browser tab? 4) Not the problem, but have you considered using some kind of auto-refresh extension for your browser?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
1. I haven't found any dependency, it's just stop working.
3. Ctrl+R is a habit. I tried to switch to F5 with no result.
4. No, I need to refresh page only when I ask browser for it

Comment: 2 is now testing. Thank you very much. It looks like all is well

Comment: Nice. I'll post an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two improvements:

1. Use `#If(...)` for context-sensitive hotkeys whenever possible. In my experience, `#If` is more reliable due to various reasons. Also, you won't have to worry about non-affected windows (e.g. by deciding what to send); in fact, I believe that non-affected windows receive the original native keystrokes if the `#If...` condition comes up false.
2. AHK_L has a cool window selector called `ahk_exe` which lets you identify windows by their process name, rather than their class/title. It's possible that different windows of the same program have different class names, e.g. Windows Media Player in minimized/maximized mode. Possibly, Skype has that, too. That's why for more complex applications, it is often reasonable to identify by process name.

Mixing these suggestions into a solution, we get this brief piece of code:

```
; I hope it's skype.exe ;)
#IfWinActive ahk_exe skype.exe
^r::return
```

Instead of programmatically saying *"If the active window isn't Skype, we send <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>"*, we're now saying *"If the window **is** Skype, we do nothing"*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SendMode, Input ; <---typically more reliable than send play mode
~$*^r:: ;<--- ~ means pass command to machine * means fire regardless of other hotkey modifiers.

Send, {Blind}{Ctrl Down}
Send, {R}         
Send, {Ctrl Up}   
return
```

I use a program called ACT! for my database. Whenever I script hotkeys it like to be sent commands like this vs. what you initially had (not that it was wrong).

If that doesn't work you could try adding: Sleep, 50 between each send (produces a delay) to see if that works. If so, you can cut each delay by 1/2 until it stops working again.

-islanq

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Autohotkey

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class tSkMainForm ;Skype
;prevent call
^r::
#IfWinActive
```